# Does $A$ is equipollent to $B$ $\implies $ $P(A)$ is equipollent to $P(B)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A, B$ be sets and let $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ denote their powersets.

Suppose there is a bijection $f: A\to B$. Is there a bijection $g:P(A)\to P(B)$?

I feel like it is true, but I have trouble writing down and explicit formula for $g$.

Comment: Another related post: [Suppose X~Y, Prove that P(X) ~ P(Y)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1862888)

Answer (score 2):

$$g(X)=\{f(a):a\in X\}\quad\forall X\subset A$$

Answer (score 0):

$$|P(A)|=2^{|A|}=2^{|B|}=|P(B)|$$

and this is true no matter what the cardinality of $\;A\,,\,B\;\;$ is

Comment: However, this is hard to use (though not impossible) if $A$ and $B$ are infinite.

Comment: @GFauxPas No it's not. This is standard cardinal arithmetic.

Comment: I just meant that if the OP is learning about basic results of cardinality, they might not be expected to know cardinals.

Comment: Cantor's Theorem is, I believe, one of the first things that's learned in set theory, and so are cardinals. As I've no idea what's the OP's level, I'm assuming as little as possible...but at university level, of course.