# reference request for cardinal number and topology

Tags: general-topology

This problem is really surprising how some of these cardinal numbers can be invariants.

How to find some references to this subject. Or I just have to prove this because they are just simple facts to remember.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Willard just wants you to prove these statements. By "has cardinal number $\aleph$," I'm sure means that the set has cardinality $\aleph$. Now, given two spaces that are homeomorphic, say $h : X \to Y$ is a homeomorphism, assuming that $X$ has one of the properties listed (1 through 5), you want to show that $Y$ also has that property. You may also visit [Suppose X~Y, Prove that P(X) ~ P(Y)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862888) for a question that might be relevant to one of these properties.

*Edit:* To show that a property is **not** a topological property, you want to construct a homeomorphism $h : X \to Y$ that doesn't preserve the indicated property. For example, if $X = \mathbb R$ with the metric $\rho : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ defined by $\rho(x,y) = \min\{ |x-y| , 1 \}$ (you can check that this is a metric which is compatible with the usual topology on $\mathbb R$), then the property that $\rho$ is bounded (in particular, by $1$), is not a topological property. In fact the identity $\mathrm{id} : (X,\rho) \to (X,d)$ where $d$ is the standard metric $|x-y|$ is a homeormorphism, but the metric space $(X,d)$ is not bounded.

*Another edit:* If you want to read about other cardinal invariant properties in topology, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_function lists a few.

Comment: A very good counterexample for the item 6: "The topology is generated by the metric $\rho$". Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to ask the question: is this property of the topological space $X$ still true if I replace $X$ by some other space $Y$ that is homeomorphic to $X$? If so the property is topological, if not it isn't.

For problems $1$ to $5$, I think it is easy to see that the above holds: e.g., in problem $3$ if $X$ has a basis $B$ of cardinality $\aleph_1$, and $f: X \to Y$ is a homeomorphism, then $\{f(U) : U \in B\}$ will be a basis for $Y$ of cardinality $\aleph_1$.

For problem $7$, it is easy to see that the above fails to hold: e.g., the singleton set $\{(0, 1)\} \subseteq \Bbb{R}^2$ is not a subset of $\Bbb{R}$ but it is homeomorphic to $\{0\}$ which is a subset of $\Bbb{R}$.

The meaning of $6$ is a little bit unclear, because the dependency on $\rho$ is not stated: I think the point is that you can't recover the metric $\rho$ (if it exists) from the topology on $X$, e.g., if $\rho$ is any metric then so is $2\rho$ (and there are many more interesting examples). On a possible alternative reading, if you are given the metric $\rho$, then just replacing $X$ by a homeomorphic space $Y$ just by renaming all the elements gives you a space to which the metric $\rho$ just doesn't apply.

Comment: Although proving that $\{(0, 1)\}$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ relies very much on the precise representation of pairs and real numbers in material set theory, so it's not totally trivial.

Comment: @MarkSaving: I know where you are coming from, but in this instance I don't want to go there (if you will forgive the clichés). I'll just leave this comment to provide the more rigorous observation that not every element of $\Bbb{P}(\Bbb{R})$ can be an element of $\Bbb{R}$,  therefore there is a singleton set that is not equal to $\{0\}$. What I wrote in the answer works fine for the usual "typed" understanding of set theory in day-to-day mathematics.