# Bijective set function between $2^X$ and $2^Y$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

How Can I prove the following?

$f: X ⇒ Y$ is a bijective function implies $f: 2^X ⇒ 2^Y$ is bijective

Comment: Hey Abid, people will be more receptive to helping you if you show that you have made an honest attempt! What have you tried?

Comment: I am able to gather my thought process and proceed.

Comment: [Suppose X~Y, Prove that P(X) ~ P(Y)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1862888) or [Does $A$ is equipollent to $B$ $\implies $ $P(A)$ is equipollent to $P(B)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1035134)

Comment: This follows from the functoriality of $X\mapsto 2^X$.

Comment: Two different by bijections are involved. They can’t both be called $f$.